# Debian 9 does not find AAAA record for IPv6-only DNS names

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, debian, ipv6

I have an AAAA-only DNS name: `superdns.cyberfusion.cloud`. Using `nslookup` without options on Debian 9, I get `No answer`. Using `nslookup` without options on Ubuntu, I get the correct answer (AAAA record). I cannot reproduce this behaviour on Debian 10, though...

Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ nslookup superdns.cyberfusion.cloud
Server:     2a0c:eb00:0:f7:185:233:175:142
Address:    2a0c:eb00:0:f7:185:233:175:142#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   superdns.cyberfusion.cloud
Address: 2a0c:eb00:0:f7:185:233:175:211
```

Debian 9 in my network:

```
$ nslookup superdns.cyberfusion.cloud
Server:     2a0c:eb00:0:f7:185:233:175:142
Address:    2a0c:eb00:0:f7:185:233:175:142#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find superdns.cyberfusion.cloud: No answer
```

Debian 10 in my network:

```
$ nslookup superdns.cyberfusion.cloud
Server:     185.233.175.142
Address:    185.233.175.142#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   superdns.cyberfusion.cloud
Address: 2a0c:eb00:0:f7:185:233:175:211
```

Debian 9 **outside** my network using Cloudflare DNS:

```
$ nslookup superdns.cyberfusion.cloud
Server:     1.1.1.1
Address:    1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find superdns.cyberfusion.cloud: No answer
```

So, I started looking at differences between these three machines, but could not find any significant lookup-related configuration errors:

Same `gai.conf` on all machines:

```
label ::1/128 0
label ::/0 1
label 2002::/16 2
label ::/96 3
label ::ffff:0:0/96 4
label fec0::/10 5
label fc00::/7 6
```

No `systemd-resolved` on all machines:

```
$ systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
           └─resolvconf.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

And, as mentioned before, I have tested on two Debian 9 machines with different resolvers in use.

The only common characteristic I could find is that the machines with 'wrong' behaviour run Debian 9, whereas the machines with 'correct' behaviour run either Ubuntu or Debian 10. I have searched Debian 10 changelogs for IPv6-related changes, but could not find many.

This behaviour is not specific to `nslookup`. I use some Ruby DNS library that does not find the AAAA record on the machines where `nslookup` is not finding my AAAA records, but does find the AAAA record on the machines where `nslookup` is finding my AAAA records, so this must be a system-wide setting.

Question: aside from `/etc/gai.conf`, which mechanism controls whether to look for AAAA records at all?

Comment: Prefer `dig` over `nslookup` but in both cases if I am not wrong, if you do not specify the type, an `A` type query is done. If you want `AAAA` you need to specify it explicitely (and it is good practice anyway). Both are doing DNS queries themselves so they do not care about `gai.conf` or if a local resolver runs or not (you can specify which nameserver you want to query which is always something good to do explicitely)

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the nslookup contained in the dnsutils package:

- Debian 9: 9.10.3
- Debian 10: 9.11.5
- Ubuntu 18.04: 9.11.3

I believe that the functionality you are missing in Debian 9 (9.10.3) was introduced with this commit:

[4420. [func] nslookup now looks for AAAA as well as A by default.](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/commit/e7e7efe90155b73bb836bf433abe25330183c8a0)

It was then released as a beta- and release candidate-version both of which later became the stable 9.11.0 of bind and its utils.

In order to obtain a later version for Debian 9, you may check out the stretch-backports repository, which will enable you to install 9.11.5 in a clean manner on Debian 9.